# Problems saving data in added fields to a javascript form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**Abstract:** I'm attempting to add fields to a sort of online personal profile for members in an organization, written in javascript.  I'm really REALLY new to this language and so I'm finding myself in need of some help.

**Background (what's working):** The script allows a user to click an "add" button, fill out a form with basic fields (first name, last name, position, photo, blah blah blah) and then store the data in a mysql database through a php script.  Once the person is added, they go into a list that displays photo and name; profiles can be edited by clicking on each photo  The user can add as may people as desired.  See image below to get an idea of the interface (images/names of real people have been pixilated to protect the innocent...from...something):

[image: People Interface]

**What I'm trying to do (what's not working):** So all that works great...probably because I didn't write that part.  The trouble comes when I try to add a set of fields (ownership_percentage, edu, skills, prof, awards, community, years, & compensation) to the pop-up form right below the original fields:

```
    createForm: function(n) {
        item = $("<table> \
            <tr><th>Name</th><td class='twoinput'><input name='pfname' placeholder='Jane'/><input name='plname' placeholder='Smith'/></tr> \
            <tr><th>Title</th><td><input name='ptitle' placeholder='Chief Executive Officer'/></tr> \
            <tr><th>Short Bio</th><td><textarea name='pbio'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Photo</th><td><input id='photo_upload' name='photo'/> <input type='button' id='photo_button' value='Open Media Library'/></tr> \
            <tr><td colspan='2'>(Optional) Upload a photo of <acronym title='Replace this with their first name?'>this person</acronym>. The bigger the better&mdash;don't worry, we'll scale this down for you.</td></tr> \
            </table>\
            <br/>\
            <table>\
            <tr><th>Education</th><td><textarea name='pedu'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Relevant Skills</th><td><textarea name='pskills'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Professional Experience</th><td><textarea name='pprof'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Awards & Recognition</th><td><textarea name='pawards'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Community Involvement</th><td><textarea name='pcommunity'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Years with the Company</th><td><input type='text' size='2' maxlength='2' name='pyears'/>years</td></tr>\
            <tr><th>Compensation Details</th><td><textarea name='pcompensation'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            </table>\
            <br/>\
            <table>\
            <tr><td id='ownershipquestion' colspan='2'>Does this person have an ownership stake?</td><td id='ownershipbox'><input type='checkbox' id='part_owner' name='owner' value='1'/>Yes</td></tr>\
            <tr><td id='ownershipperquestion' colspan='2'>What percentage does this person hold?</td><td id='ownershipperanswer'><input type='text' size='3' maxlength='3' id='ownership_percentage' name='ownership_percentage'/>%</td></tr>\
        </table>");
        if(n < upsmart.people.people.length) {
            p = upsmart.people.people[n];
            item.find("input[name=pfname]").attr("value",p.fname);
            item.find("input[name=plname]").attr("value",p.lname);
            item.find("input[name=ptitle]").attr("value",p.title);
            item.find("textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value",p.bio);
            item.find("input[name=photo]").attr("value",p.photo);
            item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("value",p.owner);
            item.find("input[name=ownership_percentage]").attr("value",p.ownership_percentage);
            item.find("input[name=pedu").attr("value",p.edu);
            item.find("input[name=pskills").attr("value",p.skills);
            item.find("input[name=pprof").attr("value",p.prof);
            item.find("input[name=pawards").attr("value",p.awards);
            item.find("input[name=pcommunity").attr("value",p.community);
            item.find("input[name=pyears").attr("value",p.years);
            item.find("input[name=pcompensation").attr("value",p.compensation);
        }
        return item;
    },
```

and

```
        var person = {
            id: $("#dialog").data("person"),
            fname: $("#dialog input[name=pfname]").attr("value"),
            lname: $("#dialog input[name=plname]").attr("value"),
            title: $("#dialog input[name=ptitle]").attr("value"),
            bio:   $("#dialog textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value"),
            photo: $("#dialog input[name=photo]").attr("value"),
            owner: $("#dialog input[name=owner]").attr("value"),
            ownership_percentage: $("#dialog input[name=ownership_percentage]").attr("value"),
            edu: $("#dialog input[name=pedu]").attr("value"),
            skills: $("#dialog input[name=pskills]").attr("value"),
            prof: $("#dialog input[name=pprof]").attr("value"),
            awards: $("#dialog input[name=pawards]").attr("value"),
            community: $("#dialog input[name=pcommunity]").attr("value"),
            years: $("#dialog input[name=pyears]").attr("value"),
            compensation: $("#dialog input[name=pcompensation]").attr("value"),
        }
```

**The Problem (how it's not working):**

- These new fields display just fine on the pop-up when I click the plus button
- ...but don't save any data, though it does not inhibit the storing of anything listed above "ownership_percentage" in the code above.
- With these new fields present I cannot edit any existing information by clicking on the images (nothing pops up).
- When I save the form I get "Undefined Property" error messages for every new field, regardless of whether or not it has data.

I've checked the php save script and everything is in order; it seems as though I'm missing something in my javascript to pass these new values into an array for the php to process..  I cannot think of what might be causing this difference and am looking for ideas.

**Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks very much in advance!**

[Here's a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/People_code.txt) to a txt file containing

1. The php function calling the javascript and receiving its output
2. The php function that saves the output to a database
3. The javascript in question

Comment: What happens with this `person` object once you've made it? Presumably it must be sent up to the server somewhere, and the server must have some php that interprets it. Have you looked at those pieces of code?

Comment: @user1618143 Hi, thanks for the reply.  The javascript is called by php and returns an array.  This works just fine for all non-new fields when I'm adding a new person and, if I delete the new fields, I can edit the existing profiles just fine.  However with the new fields present, I cannot.  I'll provide a link to the code in the post above.

Comment: That can't be right. PHP is incapable of calling javascript. PHP lives on the server and the javascript lives on the client - they can't talk without some kind of intermediary. PHP can build a web page that will run some javascript, but the javascript can't send messages back without some sort of call back to the server. Fortunately, you don't have to build that network stuff; it's already built. You just have to find it. There should be some javascript that sends a request to the server, and some PHP on the server that handles that request.

Comment: @user1618143 Hah, quite right; thanks for the correction.  The situation is as you describe above.  (I'm pretty new to web development and so my word-usage is often a little wonky.)  The php and javascript about which you're speaking can be [found here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/People_code.txt)  The corresponding php seems to process everything properly except for data from those new fields in question.

Comment: Well, that's probably part of your problem - you need to edit the php to process the data from the new fields. Where are these undefined property errors showing up - in the browser console?

Comment: @user1618143 I found the errors in my apache error log upon saving the form that contains the javascript.  The php in charge of saving the data to the database has already been altered in accordance with all new fields.  The php function that generates the page does not address any field specifically and, I beleve, receives the output with $out .= "upsmart.people.finishAddPerson(".json_encode($p).");\n";

Comment: @user1618143 Turns out I'm getting an "unrecognized expression" error for each one of my new fields.  I don't know what to do with it off the top of my head, but this seems like a relevant lead.

Comment: Did you add appropriate fields to your database?

Comment: @user1618143 Posted a question regarding the "unrecognized expression error" and got the solution: Was missing closing brackets on all my new fields.  :-P  sorry for the anticlimactic ending; thanks for trying to give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Anticlimactic solution courtesy of RUJordan on a separate question that I posted about the "unrecognized expression error"

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18541225/2540204

The issue was I was missing closing brackets on all my new form fields so

```
        if(n < upsmart.people.people.length) {
            p = upsmart.people.people[n];
            item.find("input[name=pfname]").attr("value",p.fname);
            item.find("input[name=plname]").attr("value",p.lname);
            item.find("input[name=ptitle]").attr("value",p.title);
            item.find("textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value",p.bio);
            item.find("input[name=photo]").attr("value",p.photo);
            item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("value",p.owner);
            item.find("input[name=ownership_percentage]").attr("value",p.ownership_percentage);
            item.find("input[name=pedu").attr("value",p.edu);
            item.find("input[name=pskills").attr("value",p.skills);
            item.find("input[name=pprof").attr("value",p.prof);
            item.find("input[name=pawards").attr("value",p.awards);
            item.find("input[name=pcommunity").attr("value",p.community);
            item.find("input[name=pyears").attr("value",p.years);
            item.find("input[name=pcompensation").attr("value",p.compensation);
        }
```

**Became**

```
        if(n < upsmart.people.people.length) {
            p = upsmart.people.people[n];
            item.find("input[name=pfname]").attr("value",p.fname);
            item.find("input[name=plname]").attr("value",p.lname);
            item.find("input[name=ptitle]").attr("value",p.title);
            item.find("textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value",p.bio);
            item.find("input[name=photo]").attr("value",p.photo);
            item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("value",p.owner);
            item.find("input[name=ownership_percentage]").attr("value",p.ownership_percentage);
            item.find("input[name=pedu]").attr("value",p.edu);
            item.find("input[name=pskills]").attr("value",p.skills);
            item.find("input[name=pprof]").attr("value",p.prof);
            item.find("input[name=pawards]").attr("value",p.awards);
            item.find("input[name=pcommunity]").attr("value",p.community);
            item.find("input[name=pyears]").attr("value",p.years);
            item.find("input[name=pcompensation]").attr("value",p.compensation);
        }
```