# "unrecognized expression" in new form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm running into a situation where I have a form written in javascript that creates profiles for people detailing the ir name bio etc.  Anyway, I tried to add some new fields to this form but each new field that I added is throwing an "unrecognized expression" error when I try to edit the profile information.

All fields from "fname" to "owner" are just fine but anything below that throws the error.  consistent with the explanation above, all fields below "owner" are new fields that I recently added.

```
    createForm: function(n) {
        item = $("<table> \
            <tr><th>Name</th><td class='twoinput'><input name='pfname' placeholder='Jane'/><input name='plname' placeholder='Smith'/></tr> \
            <tr><th>Title</th><td><input name='ptitle' placeholder='Chief Executive Officer'/></tr> \
            <tr><th>Short Bio</th><td><textarea name='pbio'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Photo</th><td><input id='photo_upload' name='photo'/> <input type='button' id='photo_button' value='Open Media Library'/></tr> \
            <tr><td colspan='2'>(Optional) Upload a photo of <acronym title='Replace this with their first name?'>this person</acronym>. The bigger the better&mdash;don't worry, we'll scale this down for you.</td></tr> \
            </table>\
            <br/>\
            <table>\
            <tr><th>Education</th><td><textarea name='pedu'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Relevant Skills</th><td><textarea name='pskills'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Professional Experience</th><td><textarea name='pprof'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Awards & Recognition</th><td><textarea name='pawards'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Community Involvement</th><td><textarea name='pcommunity'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            <tr><th>Years with the Company</th><td><input type='text' size='2' maxlength='2' name='pyears'/>years</td></tr>\
            <tr><th>Compensation Details</th><td><textarea name='pcompensation'/></textarea></td></tr> \
            </table>\
            <br/>\
            <table>\
            <tr><td id='ownershipquestion' colspan='2'>Does this person have an ownership stake?</td><td id='ownershipbox'><input type='checkbox' id='part_owner' name='owner' value='1'/>Yes</td></tr>\
            <tr><td id='ownershipperquestion' colspan='2'>What percentage does this person hold?</td><td id='ownershipperanswer'><input type='text' size='3' maxlength='3' id='ownership_percentage' name='ownership_percentage'/>%</td></tr>\
        </table>");
        if(n < upsmart.people.people.length) {
            p = upsmart.people.people[n];
            item.find("input[name=pfname]").attr("value",p.fname);
            item.find("input[name=plname]").attr("value",p.lname);
            item.find("input[name=ptitle]").attr("value",p.title);
            item.find("textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value",p.bio);
            item.find("input[name=photo]").attr("value",p.photo);
            item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("value",p.owner);
            item.find("input[name=ownership_percentage]").attr("value",p.ownership_percentage);
            item.find("input[name=pedu").attr("value",p.edu);
            item.find("input[name=pskills").attr("value",p.skills);
            item.find("input[name=pprof").attr("value",p.prof);
            item.find("input[name=pawards").attr("value",p.awards);
            item.find("input[name=pcommunity").attr("value",p.community);
            item.find("input[name=pyears").attr("value",p.years);
            item.find("input[name=pcompensation").attr("value",p.compensation);
        }
        return item;
    },
```

**An example of the exact wording of an error messages is:**

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=pedu

All relevant javascript functions can be [viewed here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/People_java.txt)

Thanks in advance.

Note: this is an evolution of the problem described in the post: [Problems saving data in added fields to a javascript form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539542/problems-saving-data-in-added-fields-to-a-javascript-form)

Comment: Note that to set form field values you can say `.val(p.fname)` rather than `.attr("value",p.fname)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot several `]` in your jQuery selectors at the end

Edit: from 'pedu' and down, just add those final braces and that should be all of them.

Comment: ::Jaw drops, face turns red, head hits table::  Works perfectly!  I've been at this for probably 8 hours now.  After all that, I was hoping to find out something I didn't know about javascript; I already know that I'm terrible at syntax! :-)  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

you are missing several closing brackets.

```
item.find("input[name=pedu").attr("value",p.edu);
```

should be

```
item.find("input[name=pedu]").attr("value",p.edu);
```